# Making a table as a box in beamer in whch 2 cells are highlighted

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to make a table similar to:
[How to construct  a confusion matrix in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20267/how-to-construct-a-confusion-matrix-in-latex/)

I prefer to do it in tikz.  I would also like to highlight 2 cells in the same row or 2 cells in the same column as in: [Highlighting table cells](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4850/highlighting-table-cells)
If the 2 cells cannot be circled, highlighting them in another way would also be awesome.

I would also like to do this in beamer.

I am also not fully sure how to center this figure--or generally--how to adjust its position within the beamer slide.

I would be very grateful for any help!  Thank you in advance.

I have modified the tikz code in the earlier solution on just setting up the box (without any highlighting), but when  add \begin{frame} and \end{frame} it no longer compiles:

```
\documentclass[professionalfont, fleqn]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,fit,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
box/.style={draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.0cm,text width=1cm,align=center}]
\matrix (conmat) [row sep=0cm,column sep=0cm] {
\node (tpos) [box,
label=left:\( \mathbf{p'} \),
label=above:\( \mathbf{p} \),
] {};
&
\node (fneg) [box,
label=above:\textbf{n},] {$\checkmark$};
\\
\node (fpos) [box,
label=left:\( \mathbf{n'} \),] {$\checkmark$};
&
\node (tneg) [box] {$\checkmark$};
\\
};
\node [left=.05cm of conmat,text width=1.5cm,align=center] {\textbf{actual \\ value}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{prediction outcome}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `fragile` option for the frame:

```
\documentclass[professionalfont, fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,fit,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style = {draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.0cm,text width=1cm,align=center}
]
\matrix (conmat) [row sep=0cm,column sep=0cm] {
\node (tpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{p'} \),label=above:\( \mathbf{p} \),] {};
  & \node (fneg) [box,label=above:\textbf{n},] {$\checkmark$}; \\
\node (fpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{n'} \),] {$\checkmark$};
  & \node (tneg) [box] {$\checkmark$}; \\
};

\node [left=.05cm of conmat,text width=1.5cm,align=center] {\textbf{actual \\ value}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{prediction outcome}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To control the positioning, you can use  some standard commands such as `\centering`, `\vfill`, `\vspace` or `\hspace`.

An example showing two alternatives to fill columns or rows; the first one using an argumant for the `box` style (each \node can then be filled with an independent color) and the second one using `column <number>/.style`, and/or `row <number>/.style` to apply the color to a whole column or row:

```
\documentclass[professionalfont, fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,fit,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\vspace*{-1cm}\hspace*{2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style = {draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.0cm,text width=1cm,align=center,fill=#1}
]
\matrix (conmat) [row sep=0cm,column sep=0cm] {
\node (tpos) [box=white,label=left:\( \mathbf{p'} \),label=above:\( \mathbf{p} \),] {};
  & \node (fneg) [box=blue!40,label=above:\textbf{n},] {$\checkmark$}; \\
\node (fpos) [box=white,label=left:\( \mathbf{n'} \),] {$\checkmark$};
  & \node (tneg) [box=blue!40] {$\checkmark$}; \\
};

\node [left=.05cm of conmat,text width=1.5cm,align=center] {\textbf{actual \\ value}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{prediction outcome}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[column 1/.style={every node/.style={fill=red!30}},
  box/.style = {draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.0cm,text width=1cm,align=center}
]
\matrix (conmat) [row sep=0cm,column sep=0cm] {
\node (tpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{p'} \),label=above:\( \mathbf{p} \),] {};
  & \node (fneg) [box,label=above:\textbf{n},] {$\checkmark$}; \\
\node (fpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{n'} \),] {$\checkmark$};
  & \node (tneg) [box] {$\checkmark$}; \\
};

\node [left=.05cm of conmat,text width=1.5cm,align=center] {\textbf{actual \\ value}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{prediction outcome}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[row 2/.style={every node/.style={fill=olive!30}},
  box/.style = {draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.0cm,text width=1cm,align=center}
]
\matrix (conmat) [row sep=0cm,column sep=0cm] {
\node (tpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{p'} \),label=above:\( \mathbf{p} \),] {};
  & \node (fneg) [box,label=above:\textbf{n},] {$\checkmark$}; \\
\node (fpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{n'} \),] {$\checkmark$};
  & \node (tneg) [box] {$\checkmark$}; \\
};

\node [left=.05cm of conmat,text width=1.5cm,align=center] {\textbf{actual \\ value}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{prediction outcome}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this response!  Where exactly do I place the \vspace and \hspace commands?  Before the \begin{tikzpicture}?

Comment: Also, how can these cells be highlighted?  I would like to highlight ether one of the rows or one of the columns.  Either circling it or possibly just highlighting the 2 cells.

Comment: @JG To your first question; yes. For the second question, please see my updated answer.

Comment: How can this work with the \only<1>{ } command?  I'm getting compiling issues when i try that

Comment: @JG that depends on what exactly you are trying to do; please elaborate; even better, since apparently your question isn't directly related to the issue of this one, but it's related, I would suggest you to accept the answer to this one and to open a [follow-up question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/3954).