# making a box in beamer -- pausing within frame to show new content using only

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am trying to use the only<1>, only<2>, etc... feature of beamer for a frame.  However, when  add it to the program, it is not compiling.  I would appreciate any help.

Also, how can the titles, "prediction outcomes" and "actual outcomes" be centered rather than left-aligned?

Where is there a list of beamer color options (instead of blue as is in the code)?

How can I make an arrow to point to the cell?

This is continued from: [Making a table as a box in beamer in whch 2 cells are highlighted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64705/making-a-table-as-a-box-in-beamer-in-whch-2-cells-are-highlighted/64707#64707)

```
\documentclass[professionalfont, fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,fit,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}[fragile]

 \centering
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style = {draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.0cm,text width=1cm,align=center}
 ]
 \matrix (conmat) [row sep=0cm,column sep=0cm] {
 \node (tpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{p'} \),label=above:\( \mathbf{p} \),] {};
 & \node (fneg) [box,label=above:\textbf{n},] {$\checkmark$}; \\
 \node (fpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{n'} \),] {$\checkmark$};
  & \node (tneg) [box] {$\checkmark$}; \\
 };

\node [left=.05cm of conmat,text width=1.5cm,align=center] {\textbf{actual \\ value}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{prediction outcome}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I tried putting the only around the begin{tikzpicture} and end{tikzpicture}.

Comment: There are many questions in here, can you please make it more to the point? Also there are no `\only` commands right now. When does it not work? Also there is no arrow now. Can you make it a complete code compatible with the question?

Comment: Colour processing in beamer and tikz comes from the xcolor package.  That can be loaded with vast lists of named colours.  See the xcolor documentation for details.  If you put `\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}` at the very start of the document to load the svgnames, for example.

Comment: Where is the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm answering the `\only` part as I judge that the main question here.)

It doesn't look like it on the surface, but this is the same underlying problem as your original question: when using a matrix in a tikzpicture, the ampersand must not be seen too early.  With the `\begin{frame} ... \end{frame}` construction of the original question then the whole frame is read in before it is processed, and this means that the ampersand is read too early.  The `fragile` option is a work-a-round for this.  However, the `fragile` option only works for the `\begin{frame} ... \end{frame}` construction.  When you enclose the tikzpicture in an `\only` then once again the whole picture is read in (as it is the argument to the `\only` command) before it is processed so the ampersand is read too early.  There are ways around this, for example using `\onslide<1>` before the tikzpicture, but these might not interact well with more complicated overlay specifications.

There is an alternative way to get round this ampersand issue and this is what I recommend in this case.  That is to use the key `ampersand replacement` in the argument to the `matrix` path construction.  The most common use is: `\matrix[..., ampersand replacement=\&,...] { ... \& ... \\ };` but any command can be used.  This command is used to replace the ampersand in the matrix construction.  Thus:

```
\documentclass[professionalfont, fleqn]{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/64774/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning,fit,shapes.misc}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}

 \centering
\only<1>{%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style = {draw,rectangle,minimum size=1.0cm,text
width=1cm,align=center}
 ]
 \matrix (conmat) [row sep=0cm,column sep=0cm,ampersand
replacement=\&] {
 \node (tpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{p'} \),label=above:\(
\mathbf{p} \),] {};
  \& \node (fneg) [box,label=above:\textbf{n},] {$\checkmark$}; \\
 \node (fpos) [box,label=left:\( \mathbf{n'} \),] {$\checkmark$};
  \& \node (tneg) [box] {$\checkmark$}; \\
 };

\node [left=.05cm of conmat,text width=1.5cm,align=center]
{\textbf{actual \\ value}};
\node [above=.05cm of conmat] {\textbf{prediction outcome}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\pause
Second frame

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This will be the most robust solution for you, I think.