# Decreasing size of confusion matrix

Tags: tables, graphics, arrays, multirow

I used proposed code in [How to construct a confusion matrix in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20267/how-to-construct-a-confusion-matrix-in-latex) to create a confusion matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcommand\MyBox[2]{
  \fbox{\lower0.75cm
    \vbox to 1.7cm{\vfil
      \hbox to 1.7cm{\hfil\parbox{1.4cm}{#1\\#2}\hfil}
      \vfil}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{c >{\bfseries}r @{\hspace{0.7em}}c @{\hspace{0.4em}}c @{\hspace{0.7em}}l}
  \multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1.1cm}{\bfseries\centering actual\\ value}}} & 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Prediction outcome} & \\
  & & \bfseries p & \bfseries n & \bfseries total \\
  & p$'$ & \MyBox{True}{Positive} & \MyBox{False}{Negative} & P$'$ \\[2.4em]
  & n$'$ & \MyBox{False}{Positive} & \MyBox{True}{Negative} & N$'$ \\
  & total & P & N &
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a little big for my two columns article. How can I decease (scale) size of it?

**Ps.**

I'm using `\documentclass[conference,hidelinks]{IEEEtran}` as document class.

Comment: Your MWE doesn't feature a two-column layout, so it's a bit hard to judge the seriousness of the problem. If I add the option `twocolumn` to the `\documentclass` instruction of your example code, the matrix fits perfectly well in the available space. Upshot: please indicate in more detail how you set up two-column mode for your document.

Comment: Thank you for your commnet. `\documentclass[conference,hidelinks]{IEEEtran}` is documentclass that I'm using.

Comment: The confusion matrix produced by the example code would appear to fit easily in the width of the columns set up by the `IEEEtran` document class. Please consider posting a screenshot to illustrate more clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Compare to table it is so big in above added screenshot.

Comment: I'm confused. So, the issue is not, then, that the matrix won't fit in the available column space? Instead, you just want to make it smaller so as to make it look more proportionate with some other table in the document?

Comment: Yes  Mico. That's true. I think this size isn't appropriate in my article.

Comment: Since you're loading the `graphicx` package, you could use that package's `\scalebox` macro to scale down the confusion matrix. Start with `\scalebox{0.8}{<code for confusion matrix>}`.

Comment: Please add your answer (edit above code with proposed `\scalebox`. + adding caption and label to it. thanks.

Comment: I've posted an answer that illustrates the use of `\scalebox`. I'm afraid I'm a dreadful psychic; I thus won't venture a guess as to what the appropriate arguments for `\caption` and `\label` may be. I trust you can figure out on your own how to provide these instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the confusion matrix, as produced by the code given in the earlier answer, is too large for your taste (even though it fits easily inside the available space), you could either edit the code to reduce the various dimensions by, say, 20 percent, or you could place the code inside a `\scalebox{0.8}{<code for confusion matrix>}` directive.

The code below uses the second approach. It shows both an unscaled confusion matrix and one that's scaled down 20 percent.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference,hidelinks]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{array,graphicx,multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\newcommand\MyBox[2]{
  \fbox{\lower0.75cm
    \vbox to 1.7cm{\vfil
      \hbox to 1.7cm{\hfil\parbox{1.4cm}{#1\\#2}\hfil}
      \vfil}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Two sizes: First unscaled, then scaled down 20\%

\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}

\begin{tabular}{c >{\bfseries}r @{\hspace{0.7em}}c @{\hspace{0.4em}}c @{\hspace{0.7em}}l}
  \multirow{11}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1.1cm}{\bfseries\centering actual\\ value}}} & 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Prediction outcome} & \\
  & & \bfseries p & \bfseries n & \bfseries total \\
  & p$'$ & \MyBox{True}{Positive} & \MyBox{False}{Negative} & P$'$ \\[2.4em]
  & n$'$ & \MyBox{False}{Positive} & \MyBox{True}{Negative} & N$'$ \\
  & total & P & N &
\end{tabular} 

\bigskip
\scalebox{0.8}{% 
\begin{tabular}{c >{\bfseries}r @{\hspace{0.7em}}c @{\hspace{0.4em}}c @{\hspace{0.7em}}l}
  \multirow{11}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox{1.1cm}{\bfseries\centering actual\\ value}}} & 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Prediction outcome} & \\
  & & \bfseries p & \bfseries n & \bfseries total \\
  & p$'$ & \MyBox{True}{Positive} & \MyBox{False}{Negative} & P$'$ \\[2.4em]
  & n$'$ & \MyBox{False}{Positive} & \MyBox{True}{Negative} & N$'$ \\
  & total & P & N &
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2] % filler text

\end{document}
```