# Confusion Matrix misalignment

Tags: tables

I'm trying to build a confusion matrix in Latex following the approach in:

[How to construct  a confusion matrix in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20267/how-to-construct-a-confusion-matrix-in-latex)

Instead of the text inside the boxes, I would like to have numbers (at the center of the each box). If I substitute the text with a number (e.g. \Mybox{x}), I get the following error: "Mysplaced alignment character tab &".

Could you help me with this?

Also I would not need the small p's and n's, but only the row/column sums.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `\MyBox` in the code that you reference takes two arguments and `{x}` is just one.It is nothing to do with being numbers or letters

Answer (score 1):

`\MyBox` in the code that you reference takes two arguments and `{x}` is just one.It is nothing to do with being numbers or letters.

Use `\MyBox{x}{y}`  or even just `\MyBox{x}{}`

Comment: Thank you David. I just need one number in the box, using \MyBox{x}{} gives me the number in the box but not centered. What should I do to make it appear in the center of the box?

Comment: @SimondeFauconval that's a different question but perhaps define it as one argument and replace `#1\\#2` by `#1`