# Create confusion matrix in Latex

Tags: matrices, overleaf

I want to Create confusion matrix  5x5 in Latex (overleaf), background same color blue.
[image]

I used this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bluewhite}{color=(white) rgb255=(90,96,191)},
            xlabel=Predicted,
            xlabel style={yshift=-30pt},
            ylabel=Actual,
            ylabel style={yshift=20pt},
            xticklabels={W1, W2, W3, W4},
            xtick={0,...,3},
            xtick style={draw=none},
            yticklabels={W1, W2, W3, W4},
            ytick={0,...,3},
            ytick style={draw=none},
            enlargelimits=false,
            colorbar,
            xticklabel style={
              rotate=90
            },
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
            nodes near coords style={
                yshift=-7pt
            },
        ]
        \addplot[
            matrix plot,
            mesh/cols=4,
            point meta=explicit,draw=gray
        ] table [meta=C] {
            x y C
            0 0 0.96
            1 0 0.1
            2 0 0
            3 0 0
            
            0 1 0.1
            1 1 0.98
            2 1 1
            3 1 0.1
            
            0 2 0
            1 2 0
            2 2 0.97
            3 2 0.3
    
            0 3 0.3
            1 3 0
            2 3 0
            3 3 1
            
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But got this output:
[image]

How I can add fifth column ( W5)?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you edit into your question any code you have made trying to make this matrix please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to construct  a confusion matrix in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20267/how-to-construct-a-confusion-matrix-in-latex)

Comment: I added my code, please how I can add fifth column W5

Comment: It still feels like you've not tried.  Even without understanding the code, I can get the fifth column without much effort.  What is your understanding of the `\addplot[]table{}` macro?

Comment: I can't get it ? please any help

Comment: Really I tried but still stock on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still confused about why you were confused.  I essentially looked through the code for every "4" (or "3") and incremented.  The only difficulty is that I couldn't have comments within the `\addplot`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            colormap={bluewhite}{color=(white) rgb255=(90,96,191)},
            xlabel=Predicted,
            xlabel style={yshift=-30pt},
            ylabel=Actual,
            ylabel style={yshift=20pt},
            xticklabels={W1, W2, W3, W4, W5}, % changed
            xtick={0,...,4}, % changed
            xtick style={draw=none},
            yticklabels={W1, W2, W3, W4, W5}, % changed
            ytick={0,...,4}, % changed
            ytick style={draw=none},
            enlargelimits=false,
            colorbar,
            xticklabel style={
              rotate=90
            },
            nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
            nodes near coords style={
                yshift=-7pt
            },
        ]
        \addplot[
            matrix plot,
            mesh/cols=5, % changed
            point meta=explicit,draw=gray
        ] table [meta=C] {
            x y C
            0 0 0.96
            1 0 0.1
            2 0 0
            3 0 0
            4 0 0
            
            0 1 0.1
            1 1 0.98
            2 1 1
            3 1 0.1
            4 1 0.02
            
            0 2 0
            1 2 0
            2 2 0.97
            3 2 0.3
            4 2 0
    
            0 3 0.3
            1 3 0
            2 3 0
            3 3 1
            4 3 0.01
    
            0 4 0
            1 4 0
            2 4 0.01
            3 4 0
            4 4 0.95
            
        }; % added every entry where x=4 or y=4
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For an output of

[image: output]